# Typescript error createing field '(' expected.ts(1005)

Tags: typescript

tsc -v returns
Version 3.2.2
Running Ubuntu and VS Code

```
import { Appearence } from "./Appearence";

export class Character {

    public constructor(){

    }

    appearence: new Appearence();
}
```

Appearence.ts contains a class in the same folder. Below are the errors

'(' expected. Line 9, 21

';' expected. Line 9, 31

Expression expected. Line 9 , 32

Declaration or statement expected. Line 10, 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
appearence: new Appearence();
```

to

```
appearence: Appearence = new Apperarence();
```